# WordPress is not creating custom image sizes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a `functions.php` file and within it, I am defining some custom image sizes to be created by WP when an image is uploaded.

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {

    // Thumbnail Size
    add_image_size('image-preview', 300);

    // Desktop 2:1
    add_image_size('image-desktop', 1920);
    add_image_size('image-desktop-crop', 1920, 960, true);

    // Tablet 8:5
    add_image_size('image-tablet', 1536);
    add_image_size('image-tablet-crop', 1536, 960, true);

    // Mobile Portrait 8:5
    add_image_size('image-mobile-portrait', 768);
    add_image_size('image-mobile-portrait-crop', 768, 480, true);

    // Mobile Landscape 2:1
    add_image_size('image-mobile-landscape', 960);
    add_image_size('image-mobile-landscape-crop', 960, 480, true);

}
```

When I dump an image object, I get something like:

```
array(39) {
["image-preview"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-preview-width"]=>
  int(300)
  ["image-preview-height"]=>
  int(187)
  ["image-desktop"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-desktop-width"]=>
  int(1536)
  ["image-desktop-height"]=>
  int(960)
  ["image-desktop-crop"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-desktop-crop-width"]=>
  int(1536)
  ["image-desktop-crop-height"]=>
  int(960)
  ["image-tablet"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-tablet-width"]=>
  int(1536)
  ["image-tablet-height"]=>
  int(960)
  ["image-tablet-crop"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-tablet-crop-width"]=>
  int(1536)
  ["image-tablet-crop-height"]=>
  int(960)
  ["image-mobile-portrait"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-mobile-portrait-width"]=>
  int(768)
  ["image-mobile-portrait-height"]=>
  int(480)
  ["image-mobile-portrait-crop"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-mobile-portrait-crop-width"]=>
  int(768)
  ["image-mobile-portrait-crop-height"]=>
  int(480)
  ["image-mobile-landscape"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-mobile-landscape-width"]=>
  int(960)
  ["image-mobile-landscape-height"]=>
  int(600)
  ["image-mobile-landscape-crop"]=>
  string(75) "https://dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/BW-divider_1536x960px.jpg"
  ["image-mobile-landscape-crop-width"]=>
  int(768)
  ["image-mobile-landscape-crop-height"]=>
  int(480)
}
```

As you can see, it has created the image sizes with the correct widths and heights, but not new image files. Instead, each URL path seems to be exactly the same, making this whole thing a bit useless. I've never had this issue before.

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to upload my images. I believe this to be a WP issue.

I am using WP version 3.9.2 - the latest as of this post.

Any idea what could be happening here?

Thanks,
Mikey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the server didn't have the GD image library for PHP. WP seemed to fail silently on this and just serve the same image for each resize.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

My developer installed GD image library and I installed the regenerate thumbnails plugin to get all the latest defined sizes.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Hope this helps someone in future.